# SQL query SELECT FROM 2 tables - equals returns correct results, but need not equals

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

Basically, I want to get all rows from the customers table that do NOT appear in the brochure_requests table.

```
SELECT *      
  FROM customers  JOIN  brochure_requests
    WHERE brochure_requests.first_name != customers.customer_first_name
    AND brochure_requests.last_name != customers.customer_last_name
```

The query works when the parameters are =, but as soon as I run a != query, the program (HeidiSQL) hangs indefinitely or until I cancel it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.

```
SELECT *      
FROM customers 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   brochure_requests
    WHERE  brochure_requests.first_name = customers.customer_first_name
    AND    brochure_requests.last_name = customers.customer_last_name)
```

I would also suggest adding an index on the `brochure_requests.first_name` and `brochure_requests.last_name` fields for improved performance.

Answer (score 5):

don't you have a customerID in the brochure_requests table?

If you do, you can do something like this:

```
select * from customers 
where customerId not in (select customerId from brochure_requests)
```

Comment: No, the tables aren't related at all, annoyingly :( they're totally independent from one another but contain a lot of the same data. Thanks though

Comment: so change the customer ID to the customer name. You will get the same result.

Comment: If the data are entered independently, you may find situations where customer John Smith-Jones has a brochure request as John Smith Jones and appears incorrectly in your result set.

Comment: KyleNZ - Unfortunately I don't have access to modify the database, otherwise I'd link these tables immediately! I can only draw data out. Diego - thanks, what you said worked :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    customers  
    LEFT JOIN brochure_requests
        ON brochure_requests.first_name = customers.customer_first_name
        AND brochure_requests.last_name = customers.customer_last_name

WHERE 
    brochure_requests.first_name IS NULL
```

Also, consider normalising your database by adding CustomerID to `brochure_requests` as a foreign key instead of duplicating the first and last names.

Comment: +1 Adding a CustomerID field would be even better than indexing the name fields.

Comment: Thanks - this isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what way does it fall short? Changing to `SELECT customers.* ...` should yield identical results to the accepted answer.